# Valores en DataList HTML, PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Me gustaría saber porque mi `datalist` almacena un número en mi base de datos en lugar del un nombre.

Me explico:

Tengo una base de datos con tabla **clientes** con los campos: **idcliente** y **nombrecliente**

Cargo el `DataList` con los clientes que hay en la BD y los guardo en otra tabla llamada `ABONOS` con campos **id_abono** y **nombrecliente**

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

     <input list="browsers" name="myBrowser"  class="form-control form- 
      control-lg">
    <datalist id="browsers" >

        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
  <option value=$valores['idcliente']>$valores['nombrecliente'].</option>

            }

  </datalist> <br>
```

Me aparece:

[image: El problema que tengo es que al seleccionar uno de los valores desplegados, me aparece el numero (idcliente) y yo necesito que se almacene el nombre(nombrecliente) en mi tabla ABONOS]

El problema que tengo es que al seleccionar uno de los valores desplegados, me aparece el número (*idcliente*) y yo necesito que se almacene el nombre (*nombrecliente*) en mi tabla **abonos**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: echo '
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">

  <h2>Complete los cuadros</h2>

  <form class="form-inline" action="includes/nuevo_prestamo.inc.php" method="POST">

  <br><br>
  <input list="browsers" name="myBrowser"  class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <datalist id="browsers" >';

         while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$valores['user_id'].'">'.$valores['user_uid'].'</option>';
                }
 
echo '</datalist> <br>';

Comment: si lo trabjas por nombres estas propenso a que 2 personas se llamen igual o no se puedean llamar igual... trabajarlo por id es mejor porque es unico! a la hora que quieras saber cuanto abono hector haces un select de abono donde el nombre_cliente o id_cliente sea igual a id unico de hector!

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero mi primary key es el nombrecliente,eso me permite que sean valores unicos, por otro lado tambien verifico en mi formulario que no se guarde un nombre que ya existe.

Pd: en mi pregunta, lo estoy manejando con ID.

Comment: Ese desplegable es por casulidad el generado por google?; pon el value del option encerrado entre comillas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que almacene el nombre del abonado y no el Id tu *option* debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
<option value="<?php echo $valores['nombrecliente']; ?>" >  <?php echo $valores['nombrecliente']; ?>  </option>
```